# Looking for the manuscript "Uniform polytopes" by N. Johnson

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes

The manuscript *Uniform Polytopes* (1991) by Norman Johnson is cited in the wikipedia page on uniform polytopes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polytope).

Is there an electronic copy of this manuscript floating around the internet somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: http://hddb.teamikaria.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1851 seems still not published ...

Comment: @WillieWong ... last time I check, the most informative post in that link (by Klitzing) was dated 7 Feb 2014.

Comment: @WillieWong: it's corrected, thanks.

Comment: @HaoCHEN: my bad! I misread the American-formatted date. Comment deleted.